# Redirecting to different $state while refreshing a $state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular UI Router, if I have two states called example-state and example-state-error. If you press F5 or browser refresh button on the example-state-error page, then it should redirect to example-state. Is there any other way to do this by using any default property of $state rather than capturing the reload event in controller and redirecting it.

Thanks, Amir Suhail

Comment: Dear Amir, did my solution helped you?

Comment: no, refresh is not captured by $stateChangeStart

Comment: strange, it worked for me. where did you put your `$rootScope.$on()`? is it within the `.run()` block?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `$stateChangeStart` event and redirect to your state in case of some condition. For this, in your `run()` block write the following:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) { 
    if (/* your conditional expression */) {
         $state.transitionTo('example-state');
    }
});
```

For more details, check the [state change events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) of ui-router.